Problème to learn logs File and find the term "ERROR"
I have a problem - the execution of my script returns

Le tableau ListeDocumentsWAF est vide.

This is my script:
# Chemin vers le fichier de log
$cheminFichierLog = "NameOfLogFile"

# Initialisation du tableau ListeDocumentsWAF
$ListeDocumentsWAF = @()

# Lecture du fichier de log
$logContent = Get-Content $cheminFichierLog
$i = 0

foreach ($ligne in $logContent) {
    Write-Host "Traitement de la ligne $i : $ligne"
    
    # Vérification que la ligne est suffisamment longue avant d'utiliser Substring
    if ($ligne.Length -ge 150 -and $ligne.Substring(25, 5) -eq "ERROR" -and $ligne.Substring(119, 30) -eq "Exception during file creation") {
        Write-Host "Ligne $i correspond aux critères d'erreur"

        # Recherche de la ligne associée au dépôt du document
        for ($j = $i - 1; $j -ge 0; $j--) {
            $lignePrecedente = $logContent[$j]
            
      if ($lignePrecedente.Length -ge 168 -and $lignePrecedente.Substring(117, 50) -eq "[UploadDocumentsAction] Attempt to upload document") {
                Write-Host "Ligne associée trouvée à l'index $j"

                # Récupération des informations entre crochets
                $matches = [regex]::Matches($lignePrecedente, '\[(.*?)\]')
                if ($matches.Count -ge 7) {
                    $StrTmp1 = $matches[2].Groups[1].Value
                    $StrTmp2 = $matches[4].Groups[1].Value
                    $StrTmp3 = $matches[6].Groups[1].Value
                    $StrTmp4 = $matches[5].Groups[1].Value
                    $StrTmp5 = $lignePrecedente.Substring(0, 19)

                    # Ajout des informations au tableau ListeDocumentsWAF
                    $ListeDocumentsWAF += @($StrTmp1, $StrTmp2, $StrTmp3, $StrTmp4, $StrTmp5)
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
    $i++
}

# Vérification si ListeDocumentsWAF contient des éléments
if ($ListeDocumentsWAF.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Le tableau ListeDocumentsWAF est vide."
} else {
    # Envoi de l'e-mail
    $liste_destinataires_mails = "[ à définir ]"
    $date_execution_au_format_YYYY_MM_DD = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $env = "[ à définir ]"
    $objet_mail = "[ Name of Project ][ $env ][ Documents bloqués par le WAF en date du $date_execution_au_format_YYYY_MM_DD ]"
    $corps_mail = @"
Bonjour,
Ci-dessous la liste des documents bloqués par le WAF le $date_execution_au_format_YYYY_MM_DD :
$ListeDocumentsWAF
"@

    # Envoi de l'e-mail
    Send-MailMessage -To $liste_destinataires_mails -Subject $objet_mail -Body $corps_mail -SmtpServer "smtp.example.com"
}

The script return Listevide that mean empty list
I want to find all que block occurence with "ERROR" in a log file and send mail to a team

The Regex is inconsistent. This means, zero or one of anything between 0 and more characters. I would advise you that if you mean that it must have between one or more characters, you use .{1,} or ..*. So your Regex becomes:
'\[(..*)\]'

The next thing is that, this Regex only generates 1 group because of 1 pair of parenthesis. To get that group you have to use the index 0, not 1. Using index 1 returns a null value. For example, you should do:
$StrTmp1 = $matches[2].Groups[0].Value

